# Python Import Text FIle as List to Iterate

Tags: python, list, import, text-files

I have a text file I want to import as a list to use in this for-while loop:

```
text_file = open("/Users/abc/test.txt", "r")
list1 = text_file.readlines
list2=[]
    for item in list1:
        number=0
        while number < 5:
            list2.append(str(item)+str(number))
            number = number + 1
    print list2
```

But when I run this, it outputs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable
```

What do I do?

Comment: It should be `text_file.readlines()` not `text_file.readlines`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`readlines()` is a method, call it:

```
list1 = text_file.readlines()
```

Also, instead of loading the whole file into a python list, iterate over the file object line by line. And [use with context manager](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement):

```
with open("/Users/abc/test.txt", "r") as f:
    list2 = []
    for item in f:
        number = 0
        while number < 5:
            list2.append(item + str(number))
            number += 1
    print list2
```

Also note that you don't need to call `str()` on `item` and you can use `+=` for incrementing the `number`.

Also, you can simplify the code even more and use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) with nested loops:

```
with open("/Users/abc/test.txt", "r") as f:
    print [item.strip() + str(number) 
           for item in f 
           for number in xrange(5)]
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

List comprehension comes to your help:

```
print [y[1]+str(y[0]) for y in list(enumerate([x.strip() for x in open("/Users/abc/test.txt","r")]))]
```